# Mongoose validation: Customise error object and custom validation

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Date field in mongoose with a validation as below -

```
endOn: {
            type: Date,
            required: true,
            validate: {
                validator: (date) => validateDate(date),
                message: 'Invalid endon',
            },
       },
```

When validation fails, this is how response looks like -

```
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "message": "Validation failed: endOn: Invalid endon",
        "stack": "ValidationError: Validation failed: endOn: Invalid endon\n ..."
    }
}
```

Even after specifying a custom error message, I get this junk value in the `error` object.

I just need it to be `"error": { "message": "Invalid endon" }`.

How can I achieve this?